# how to build a Laravel command that loops through users is sends unique emails to each user

Tags: laravel, email, command

I have a command that I'll run nightly using the Forge scheduler.  The command simply loops through and sends emails to each user who qualifies for one.

COMMAND:
public function handle()
{

```
    //Get all users
    $users = User::all();
    $data = [];
    $renewalEmail = '';
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        //Check each users next_biling_date and see if is less than 72 hours from now, if so send reminder email
        $nextBillingDate = ($user->hasSubscription())? $user->getSubscriptionData()->current_period_end : false;
        $now = strtotime(now());
        $threeDaysFromNow = 60*60*24*3;
        //($user->hasSubscription())? $this->updateNextBillingDate($user) : false;//TODO: remove after working: follow up

        if($user->hasSubscription() && $nextBillingDate-$now<=$threeDaysFromNow) 
        {
            $data = [
                'name' => $user->name,
                'billingdate' => date('n/j/Y',strtotime($user->next_billing_date)),
            ];
            // Log::info(print_r($data,true));
            $renewalEmail = Mail::to('my@email.com')->send(new SubscriptionRenewalReminder($data));
            // Log::info(print_r($renewalEmail,true));
        }
    }        
    return true;
}
```

My Mailable is pretty straight forward:

```
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    Log::info('SubscriptionRenewalReminder Email build() called: ');
    $firstName = explode(' ',$this->data['name'])[0];
    $billingDate = $this->data['billingdate'];

    Log::info('firstname: '.$firstName);
    
    Log::info('billingDate: '.$billingDate);

    return $this->view('emails.subscription-renewal-reminder')
    ->from('my@email.com', 'Project')
    ->subject('Project Subscription Is About To Renew')
    ->withName($firstName)
    ->withBillingdate($billingDate);
}
```

All of my Log::info's dump out the right information.    I have 3 test users who all qualify to get the email.

In my testing, all three emails show the first user's name and billing date.  Instead of unique emails, they are all identical.

I may move this into a queue but on a small set of users this should work fine.  TIA

Comment: Your code looks like it _should_ be generating `$data` for each separate user correctly. Do you have distinct users in your database? Maybe include your emails in the question (if you're logging them, etc) Also, nitpick, but try to avoid this kind of logic: `$firstName = explode(' ',$this->data['name'])[0];`; Names can and do have spaces in them, so assuming that the first index `[0]` of a string split on spaces is a "first name" is incorrect :)

Comment: The names and date output in the Log::info is correct.  Thats what is so frustrating. We are just using first names, thats the reason for the explode.